# H2 databse to load data only once, but on app ending not to drop data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I gave a spring boot application that uses an embedded H2. What i need is on the first start of the application, to load the data form the data.sql. Every time the application ends, or breaks, the data should be maintained. The reason for this, is that i deploy my application on heroku, which for free use, sleeps after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the database in embedded mode. See [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html).

So your datasource url have to be something like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/myDbFile;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your data.sql load conditionally and use a file H2 database see https://www.javatips.net/blog/h2-file-database-example